# How to redirect Access Denied and all other errors in Powershell to a variable (Loop until command doesnt fail)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a bootstrap script to setup servers and add them to the domain. The problem is some of the networking changes do not get implemented for a varying amount of time causing the command to join the domain to fail (always with the same error). TO get around this all I have to do is run the command again a minute later but this is not practical as part of a long script.

My solution is along the lines of:

```
$exit = 1
while ($exit -ne 0){
    $exit = 0
    join-domain-command
    $exit = $?
    sleep 20
}
```

However $exit is always 0/false even when I put in some non existent command that is bound to fail.

My other idea was to redirect all errors to a variable and search the variable for text containing the error I commonly come across and if that error is not present, stop the loop.

Trying to redirect the stderr in powershell doesn't work for me either

```
$exit = & (dummy-command -confirm:$false) 2>$exit
echo "exit = $exit"
```

SO here I deliberately set the ExecPol in an un-elevated prompt:

[image: No Exit Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use -errorvariable

```
$exit = 1
while ($exit -ne 0){
    $exit = 0
    join-domain-command -errorvariable $error
    $exit = $?
    sleep 20
}
```

Or if you want to do something with the error:

```
    try {
    join-domain-command -errorvariable $error
    }
    catch{
    $error | out-file C:\errors.txt -append
    #or if $error -contains "something" 
    #...do something
    }
```

then search the text file for your errors

**EDIT**

So a few things the actual correct use of errorVariable doesnt use the `$` so it would be `-errorvariable myError`

If you want to search an error a better way to do it would be this:

```
while ($exit -ne 0)
{ 
try {
    join-domain-command
    }
catch{
    if(!($error[0].tostring().contains("specific error text"))) #error text is not your specific error
      {$exit = 1}
    }
sleep 20
}
```

All errors can be found in `$error` and if you want to check that last error you use `$error[0]` which give you the last error that was received.

Comment: Do you mean I should replace all the $exit's with $error to test it as part of the loop?

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot convert 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter
'ErrorVariable'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:65
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Sonfirm:$false -errorvariable $error
+                                                                 ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

Comment: see my edit above.  it allows you to search the last error for a specific string.  But if the only error you get is the same all the time the best way would be to just use a `try\catch` like Tony mentions below. its more simple and basically if you get an error wait and try again

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like the following and I put it in a separate function to keep the main code path clean.  A counter can be added to limit the number of retries.

```
$Succeeded = $false
while($Succeeded -eq $false){

  try{
    #commands that may fail
    $Succeeded = $true
  }
  catch{
    #write a message or log something
  } 
  start-sleep -s 60
}
```